# Render view to variable in CakePHP 1.3 (to generate pdf and download file)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to render a view to a variable.
This variable will then be used to generate a pdf.
Then that pdf should be downloaded with the Media view.

Here's my controller code:

```
        $dir = ROOT . '/app/tmp/evaluationpdf/';
        $path = $dir . $evaluationid . '.pdf';

        $evaluation = $this->SelfEvaluation->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('SelfEvaluation.id' => $evaluationid),
            'contain' => array('Submission' => array('Application'), 'Applicant', 'Member')));

        $this->set(compact('evaluation'));
        $this->output = '';
        $this->layout = false;
        $html = $this->render('/elements/self_evaluation_pdf');

        $this->_generate_pdf($html, $path);

        $this->view = 'Media';

        $params = array(
                'id' => $evaluationid . '.pdf',
                'name' => $evaluationid,
                'download' => true,
                'extension' => 'pdf',
                'path' => $dir,
        );

        $this->set($params);
```

The file is created as it should, but the first '$this->render' output is also sent to the browser.

The file is never downloaded.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is to just set $this->output to '' after your first render() call.

The more correct way is to use requestAction() instead of render().

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 2.x I did the following in order to use a view to generate a barcode label format:

```
      $response = $this->render('/Labels/' . $printer['Printer']['model'] . '/manifest', 'ajax');
      $body = $response->body();
      $response->body('');
```

Which gave me the view data as $body.  Then I could just redirect or if the request was ajax just set autoRender to false and return ''.

It kind of muddies the MVC waters but it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write the code below in self_evaluation_pdf.ctp

```
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='downloaded.pdf'");
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

The dynamic content in this view will be downloaded as a PDF file on the client side.